# Repository and local installation

Tags: texlive

I try to install certain packages using `tlmgr install` *package*, but I keep getting

```
tlmgr: The TeX Live versions supported by the repository 
http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/2013
(2013--2013)
do not include the version of the local installation
(2014)
```

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
tlmgr install <package> --repository=http://ftp.dante.de/tex-archive/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

Comment: Thank you. It almost works. Is this the most recent repository? Does it include all packages furnished by TeX Live 2014+?

Comment: no, it is only one which could be used for a test. In general you should use `http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet`

Answer (score 2):

Your TeX Live Manager is set up to point to TLContrib for 2013. For general TeX Live updates you'd be better with the CTAN network (as most updates go there). The best plan is to use the automatic mirror system, so set

```
tlmgr option repository http://mirror.ctan.org/systems/texlive/tlnet
```

as the Admin/root user if appropriate. You can then update as normal and the nearest current mirror will be used.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Travis Continuous Integration
service](https://travis-ci.org/), your problem could be related to the CTAN
mirrors having yet to update.

The issue appears in the [Travis R community forum](https://travis-ci.community/t/latex-error-file-inconsolata-sty-not-found-only-on-osx-when-building-r-package/3261):

> might be related to the recent switch to TexLive-2019 as the LaTeX package manager seems to fail finding inconsolata in the repository.
>
> ...
>
> It looks to me like the mirror chosen was has not updated to 2019, so I think this will resolve itself naturally when the mirrors catch up. If not I can look into it.

In the meantime, I solved it by forcing a previous version of TeXLive with a downgrade to OSX 10.12 in `.travis.yml`:

```
# macOS 10.12 version
osx_image: xcode9.2
```

See [this Travis
page](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/osx#macos-version) for the
correspondence between XCode and OSX versions and [the original thread in DevOps
StackExchange](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/8012/testing-r-package-on-travis-fails-because-of-texlive-incompatible-versions/8013#8013).